# A company goes bankrupt after adopting "socialist" policies

Tags: identification-request

I think it's a chapter of some book, maybe by Ayn Rand. A company starts implementing near socialist policies, mainly focused on giving their employees what they need instead of what they have earned. For example, paid time off goes to whoever seems to need it the most. The productivity starts plummeting until the company files bankruptcy.

Comment: Good question by the way. Welcome to the site - glad to have you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is *Atlas Shrugged*.

The company in question is the 20th Century Motor Company. They implemented a policy in which everyone was expected to work according to his abilities, and everyone was paid according to his needs. Of course, things quickly descended into infighting over who could manipulate the group to meet their "needs", and people's dignity was compromised because their salary was no longer theirs by right, but only by the benevolence of the group. Naturally, morale plummeted and most of their best employees left the company (including their best engineers), so manufacturing quality slipped severely and they stopped improving their technology. They quickly went from being the best motor company to the worst (since their products were poorly manufactured and obsolete), and no one wanted their products anymore.

It later turned out that

> John Galt worked there (which is where he developed his quantum motor), and he started the Strike after they adapted the policy. He walked out from the meeting about the plan, stating that he would put a stop to it by "stop[ping] the motor of the world". (This is where the phrase "Who is John Galt?" came from - whenever people heard of factories closing, they started wondering if that was due to him making good on his threat).
>
>  His former boss there, who quit the day after the plan was adapted, was one of the first people he approached about joining the strike.